# What does typescript transpile the unary negation operator to?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find out what is recommended to check for undefined and null.

In JavaScript, Unary Operators do typecasting like two equals. What does typescript do with this, e.g.:

`if (!foo`).

Is it transpiled to

`if (foo != undefined && foo != null)`

or Crockford's recommendation like:

`if (foo !== undefined && foo !== null)`

Or is it not transpiled to anything of the sort?

Also see: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Comment: It's exactly the same as in javascript. Typescript is a superset of javascript, there's not difference in this case.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of disappointing. I miss CoffeeScript which handled the bad parts. So it is recommended to use a custom solution to handle standard error checking (null and undefined)?

Comment: That's on purpose. Typescript is javascript with type system, it won't change your code (unless you are using an advanced feature and compile it to a target that doesn't support it)

Answer (score 4):

Typescript, unlike CoffeeScript, doesn't do those sort of things, so if you have this ts code:

```
let foo;
if (!foo) {
    ...
}
```

It will compile to:

```
var foo;
if (!foo) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to avoid the need to always check things like this: `if (foo !== undefined && foo !== null)` then you can simply extract that to a function:

```
function isNothing(obj: any): boolean {
    return obj === undefined || obj === null;
}

let foo;
if (isNothing(foo)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the difference with just using `if(obj) {console.log("object exists"}` ?

Comment: @Kokodoko In most cases `if(obj)` will work just the same, but there are cases when that fails, for example if `obj  = 0`. Also, it seems that the OP wanted to check it like so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to check how your code will be transpiled.

In your case

```
var foo: any;
if (!foo) { 
}
```

will be transpiled to the

```
var foo;
if (!foo) {
}
```

with no any additional code.

So you need to write correct check code.